# R keeps using Java12 and the Broken JNI error

Tags: java, r, macos

All using OSX

Due to issues with conda Rstudio and not installing rgraphviz. I decided to fresh install Rstudio and just use it. Everything appeared to work finely until I tried to use `RJDBC` to access my database.

It worked fine when connected with anaconda but alone, I receive the following error

```
library(RJDBC)

PathDriver = "~/driver/hsqldb.jar"
JDBCDriver = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
drv <- JDBC(JDBCDriver,PathDriver)
```

> WARNING: Initial Java 12 release has broken JNI support and does NOT work. Use stable Java 11 (or watch for 12u if avaiable).

I looked up my current java version in the terminal

```
(base):$ java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1056-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b12, mixed mode)
```

confusing but either way I try to update to java 11 and reset the java R is using

```
brew cask install java11
```

and the java version still reads as `java 1.8.0`

Going into R, I still receive the error above. How do I fix this so I can use Java 11 in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run

```
R CMD javareconf
```

in the terminal to get R and Java in sync.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found that R kept configuring to the Java installed with anaconda. I uninstalled anaconda, used `sdkman` to install java 14 and now ran the command you provided. Now everything appears to work